# Matlab - Machine Learning?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

In my research progress, I have separated the parasite from the image now. the parasite looks like a worm. I want the MATLAB to read all the input images, look for the worm like dark purple image and if detected, to give out a reply saying detected. I tried using histogram comparison but I think using area or shape is a better option and it deals with machine learning. I don't know how to do that.

(http://www.cdc.gov/dpdx/lymphaticFilariasis/gallery.html#microwbancrofti)

Comment: Looks like you want an outline for an algorithm to solve your problem, but that is not specifically a programming problem. I recommend you sift through code examples for similar but more clear questions posted on SO. Look for instance into separation of the image according to color, filtering, coalescing neighboring patches into extended blobs, then measuring the shape of the resulting objects. You'll want an image processing toolbox or similar for this.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at SVMs.  However, this will require **supervised** machine learning, and so you need to train the classifier and have positive and negative examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you need to do, since the problem is not formalized, so we can't give an 100%-working algorithm.

After a glance at the pictures, I noticed that the pictures have, roughly, 3 kinds of objects:

1. Background
2. Little balls in foreground color
3. Long and curvy worm in foreground color

What can you do then:

1. Binarize the image (every pixel) into 2 colors: foreground and background. You can use either the pixel only, or its neighbors, too.
2. Find [connectivity components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) among the foreground pixels. You can represent each pixel of a picture as a node, or do something more sophisticated.
3. The bigger component would be a worm, if it's presented. You can either analyze pictures you have and come up with a threshold to discriminate worms from balls, or do something more fancy.

   For example, these balls have circular shape, so you can try to fit each connectivity component into a circle. All balls on the pictures look pretty distinct and separated, so the component with enormous radius is what you're looking for. Or, you can calculate maximum inter-component distance.

To conclude: as I said earlier, there's no exact solution to your problem. You need to try different approaches, and see what works best.